# Como chequear el funcionamiento de los jobs en laravel

Tags: laravel-7

Estoy implementando un pagina de estado de mi aplicacion, pero necesito como chequear los jobs en laravel, saber si estan funcionando o no.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como chequear status de mi app en laravel desde un controlador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/420032/como-chequear-status-de-mi-app-en-laravel-desde-un-controlador)

Comment: No dupliques preguntas por favor, sobre todo cuando ambas tienen problemas de formato, como te decía puede terminar cerrada pues es basada en opiniones